# Need to write Test method for Pagerefernce returing method

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, community, salesforce1-app, salesforce-id

I am trying to write a test for the given Main method which is returning simple PageReference..

```
Public PageReference CancelProcess(){  
    PageReference pg=New PageReference('/apex/BR_OrderMassApproval');  
    pg.setRedirect(true);
    return pg;  
    }
```

Test methd code that i am trying for this

```
public static testMethod void VerifyOrders() {
   PageReference pageRef = Page.BR_OrderMassApproval;
   Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
   Test.StartTest();
   String orders3 = foo.CancelProcess().getUrl();
   Test.stopTest();
   System.assertEquals('/apex/BR_OrderMassApproval', orders3);
}
```

I am relatively new in writing test classes can anybody please guide me what i am doing wrong in this..thanks..

Comment: I am assuming you need it to be endWith or contains.....What error are you getting?

Comment: You honestly shouldn't be using an assert for this, because you're basically testing to make sure that the system isn't corrupting memory; think of this as writing `Integer get5() { return 5; } ... System.assertEquals(5, get5());` Also, I'd discourage writing Visualforce URLs this way in code, and suggest you simply use `public PageReference cancelProcess() { PageReference r =  Page.BR_OrderMassApproval; r.setRedirect(true); return r; }`, which has the benefit of avoiding typos by using compile-time static variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL returned is the full URL so you need to use contains or endWith (if no parameters)

```
public static testMethod void VerifyOrders() {

 Test.StartTest();
   String orders3 = foo.CancelProcess().getUrl();
 Test.stopTest();

  System.assertEquals(true,orders3.contains('/apex/BR_OrderMassApproval'));

}
```

You did not need (for this test) the page reference and really do not need the test.startTest and stopTest but that is another lesson